Is there a pandoc lua-filter to filter .bib files based on keyword?
I am trying to create a bibliography with pandoc with separate lists of references based on keyword or type. For use case, think of an academic CV with separate list of publications depending on whether they are books or articles. I have all my publications in a SINGLE bib file. I can do this filtering in latex using biblatex and the \printbiography command; something like the following prints out only entries of type software:
\printbibliography[heading={subbibliography},title={Software},type={software}]

However, I want to be able to make this into html for my website and my university promotion review which requires Word (sigh). So far the only solution I have found requires me to manually separate my bib file into separate .bib files. Then I can either run them separately or use the multibib lua filter, available at https://github.com/pandoc/lua-filters/tree/master/multiple-bibliographies , which is only helpful in that I can put the separate lists into a single file.
This is very clunky: any time I update my main bib file, I have to re-separate it into separate component bib files to update the html and word documents (and I do want to maintain a single bib file, because there are use cases where there are overlapping entries between the different categories and I don't want to maintain the same reference across multiple bib files).
Is there another option? Like another lua-filter that does this task? I do not know anything about lua filters beyond my experience using the multibib one above.
Thanks!
